# How do I setup OpenGL in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: opengl

I'm looking for manuals about setup OpenGL in Visual Studio 2017, but most are old manuals about VS2010 or VS2015.
How to I setup OpenGL in VS2017? Is it different with 2015 version?

Comment: It's exactly the same as in 2013/15.

Comment: It's good. Thank you.

Comment: learnopengl.com

Answer (score -1):

If you by Visual Studio 2017 refers to the IDE itself, it can probably be set up the same way, but I have yet to successfully set it up unless I uninstall VS2015, use the earlyer SDK's (up to 8.1 works fine).
This probably has to do with my glfw-libraries/dependencies.

Anyone with pointers to the best API to set up open-gl with the windows 10 SDK I'd appreatiate a tip! Does glfw still do the trick? Can I just download the glfw source and rebuild the libraries for my win 10 version?